# What's more efficient? Icons drawn in html5 canvas or SVG icons?

Tags: html, css, canvas, svg

I'm getting into web development. I decided i want to build websites in the most efficient interactive ways possible. Using CSS3 animations, html5 syntax, and canvas. I figure i could use SVG's with the flat design being popular. This begged the question, however: should i spend the time to build icons in canvas or design in illustrator, exporting as SVG? Is there a big impact in load time?

Comment: It depends on the icons and on how you want to use them. But as this question stands it's primarily opinionbased due to the lack of detail.

Answer (score 1):

I'd settle for Canvas but [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io)  and [BootStrap from Twitter](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) combined have a huge cache of icons for web development and you should also consider CSS sprites.

Answer (score 0):

I swore in my search on google trying to identify a key with an icon and researching best practice. These links might enlighten you as to the benefits of using SVG over solutions like Font Awesome. I'm still on the fence. For rapid prototyping and retina ready icons font awesome is "an ugly hack" to get the job done. For real scalability, control, bespoke design you can create SVG graphics, backgrounds or icons that degrade greacefully and not fall over yourself when you realise you need a specific icon for a specific feature but it's not in the package.

http://technotes.iangreenleaf.com/posts/font-awesome-not-awesome.html

[Use SVG for logo on a webpage - how to have multiple instances of this logo in different colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221902/use-svg-for-logo-on-a-webpage-how-to-have-multiple-instances-of-this-logo-in-d)

Hope this helps.